# Unusual formatting of Vincenty Formulae in Java

Tags: java, format

I am in the process of taking over a project and noticed that, when the vincenty formulae is used,
it has been written in a unusual way. This is how it's written:

```
    String direct(double distance, double initialBearing, double positionlat, double positionlong)  {
        // if (this.height != 0) throw new RangeError('point must be on the surface of
        // the ellipsoid');

        double Ï†1 = this.toRad(positionlat)/* .toRadians() */, Î»1 = this.toRad(positionlong)/* .toRadians() */;
        double Î±1 = this.toRad(initialBearing);
        double s = distance;

        // allow alternative ellipsoid to be specified
        // double ellipsoid = /*this.datum ? this.datum.ellipsoid :*/
        // LatLonEllipsoidal.ellipsoids.WGS84;
        // const {a, b, f} = ellipsoid;
        double a = 6378137;
        double b = 6356752.314245;
        double f = 1 / 298.257223563;
        // double a = ellipsoid;
        // double b = ellipsoid;
        // double f = ellipsoid;

        double sinÎ±1 = Math.sin(Î±1);
        double cosÎ±1 = Math.cos(Î±1);

        double tanU1 = (1 - f) * Math.tan(Ï†1), cosU1 = 1 / Math.sqrt((1 + tanU1 * tanU1)), sinU1 = tanU1 * cosU1;
        double Ïƒ1 = Math.atan2(tanU1, cosÎ±1); // Ïƒ1 = angular distance on the sphere from the equator to P1
        double sinÎ± = cosU1 * sinÎ±1; // Î± = azimuth of the geodesic at the equator
        double cosSqÎ± = 1 - sinÎ± * sinÎ±;
        double uSq = cosSqÎ± * (a * a - b * b) / (b * b);
        double A = 1 + uSq / 16384 * (4096 + uSq * (-768 + uSq * (320 - 175 * uSq)));
        double B = uSq / 1024 * (256 + uSq * (-128 + uSq * (74 - 47 * uSq)));

        double Ïƒ = s / (b * A);
        Double sinÏƒ = null, cosÏƒ = null, Î”Ïƒ = null; // Ïƒ = angular distance Pâ‚� Pâ‚‚ on the sphere
        Double cos2Ïƒâ‚˜ = null; // Ïƒâ‚˜ = angular distance on the sphere from the equator to the midpoint of the
                                // line

        Double ÏƒÊ¹ = null, iterations = 0d;
        do {
            cos2Ïƒâ‚˜ = Math.cos(2 * Ïƒ1 + Ïƒ);
            sinÏƒ = Math.sin(Ïƒ);
            cosÏƒ = Math.cos(Ïƒ);
            Î”Ïƒ = B * sinÏƒ * (cos2Ïƒâ‚˜ + B / 4 * (cosÏƒ * (-1 + 2 * cos2Ïƒâ‚˜ * cos2Ïƒâ‚˜)
                    - B / 6 * cos2Ïƒâ‚˜ * (-3 + 4 * sinÏƒ * sinÏƒ) * (-3 + 4 * cos2Ïƒâ‚˜ * cos2Ïƒâ‚˜)));
            ÏƒÊ¹ = Ïƒ;
            Ïƒ = s / (b * A) + Î”Ïƒ;
        } while (Math.abs(Ïƒ - ÏƒÊ¹) > 1e-12 && ++iterations < 100);
        if (iterations >= 100) {
            //throw new Exception("Vincenty formula failed to converge"); // not possible?
            System.err.println("Warning: Vincenty formula failed to converge!");
        }
        

        double x = sinU1 * sinÏƒ - cosU1 * cosÏƒ * cosÎ±1;
        double Ï†2 = Math.atan2(sinU1 * cosÏƒ + cosU1 * sinÏƒ * cosÎ±1, (1 - f) * Math.sqrt(sinÎ± * sinÎ± + x * x));
        double Î» = Math.atan2(sinÏƒ * sinÎ±1, cosU1 * cosÏƒ - sinU1 * sinÏƒ * cosÎ±1);
        double C = f / 16 * cosSqÎ± * (4 + f * (4 - 3 * cosSqÎ±));
        double L = Î» - (1 - C) * f * sinÎ± * (Ïƒ + C * sinÏƒ * (cos2Ïƒâ‚˜ + C * cosÏƒ * (-1 + 2 * cos2Ïƒâ‚˜ * cos2Ïƒâ‚˜)));
        double Î»2 = Î»1 + L;

        double Î±2 = Math.atan2(sinÎ±, -x);

        // const destinationPoint = new
        // LatLonEllipsoidal_Vincenty(this.toDeg(Ï†2)/*.toDegrees()*/,
        // this.toDeg(Î»2)/*.toDegrees()*/, 0, undefined);

        return this.toDeg(Ï†2) + ";" + this.toDeg(Î»2);/*
                                                         * { lat: this.toDeg(Ï†2), lng: this.toDeg(Î»2)
                                                         */
        /*
         * destinationPoint.g point: destinationPoint, finalBearing:
         * Dms.wrap360(this.toDeg(Î±2)/*.toDegrees()
         *//*
             * ), iterations: iterations,
             */
        // };
    }
```

Now the IDE (eclipse) is responding, that it can't handle variable names such as e.g. `Ï†1`. Is there a elegant solution to fixing this or do I have to re-write it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably, the source code was written in the UTF-8 encoding, and your Eclipse is configured to interpret the sources as ANSI, ISO-8859-1, cp1252 or similar.

Then, what you see as `Ï†` is in fact the two-byte UTF-8 representation of the greek character phi (`φ`), interpreted according to ANSI.

Configure Eclipse to expect the UTF-8 encoding (Preferences / General / Workspace / Text file encoding), then it should be able to compile.

This example shows why it is a bad idea even today to use characters outside ASCII in source code.

Comment: And the wrong **Ïƒ1** is **σ1**. Somewhere in the project the encoding of the compiler, _and_ the encoding of the editor should be set to UTF-8. I advocate the usage of UTF-8, source, *.properties, XML. But a maven or gradle project infrastructure is advisable. Still +1

Comment: You were right, it was configured to use cp1252. After changing it to UTF-8, it works now. Thank you very much.